# HTTP error 500 when backup entire site

Tags: backups, http-request

Using Backup and Migrate module on a D7 site

- separate backups (data / files) give no problem (backup to nodesquirrel AND download)
- but backup entire site (data + files) generates "http error 500" (without "internal server error")

Error reporting

- I have no access to Apache error log
- Cpanel error: no error messages
- Drupal error log: no error messages

Shared hosting | db 10.1.21-MariaDB | php 5.6.30 | drupal 7.53 | backup and migrate 7.x-3.1 | civicrm 7.x-4.7.14

[update]

The web host provider received next message:

```
 Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
 with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
 General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away'
 in <drupal root>/includes/database/database.inc:2227
 Stack trace:
 #0 /includes/database/database.inc(2227): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
 #1 /includes/database/database.inc(697): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array,  Array)
 #2 /includes/database/database.inc(2406): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array)
 #3 /includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array)
 #4 /includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...')
 #5 /includes/bootstrap.inc(433): lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...')
 #6 /includes/bootstrap.inc(455): DrupalCacheArray->set(Array)
 #7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray->__destruct()
 #8 {main} in <drupal root>/includes/database/database.inc on line 2227
```

Comment: It's hard from this data to point to anything. But if a smaller backup works, I'm leaning towards memory. Instantiate `top` and try creating it. If it's not memory, maybe a timeout. For both, check your apache configuration.

Comment: @rovr138 I added the error message received by the web host provider

Comment: That MySQL error is usually due to reaching a limit on MySQL. You're going to have to break it into chunks. Would running backup-and-migrate locally be an option? You can use mysqldump to get a database and run your process locally.

Answer (score 2):

This is your error:

```
General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

You can try to fix this in two ways:

1. `my.ini`

Open your `my.ini` file and locate [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). By default this is 1M. Setting it to 16M and restart your MySQL server. If the problem persists, try setting it to 512M and restart your MySQL server.

2. `MySQL prompt`

Enter your MySQL prompt, log in as user root or as a user with the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege. Run the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 512;
```

This method doesn't require you to restart the server.

Comment: I cannot edit my.ini nor do i have super privilege in my shared host. The max_allowed_packet is 16777216.

Comment: That's 16MB which clearly isn't enough. Can you ask your hosting provider to increase that value?

Comment: It's 16 777 216 bytes = 16 MB.

Comment: The web host server provider says the unit is KB. So 16 777 216 is 16GB. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, i replaced my comment without seeing yours: the number is in bytes, not KB.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely hitting a resource limit. Enable PHP error logging in the index.php file so you can get an error output. But most likely it's a memory issue or a timeout issue which you will need to make adjustments in your PHP.ini file to fix them.

It sounds like it's specific than to your MySQL limits. Try increasing your packet size.

Here is a link that describes a similar issue with some possible solutions. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/259580

Comment: both are set to:memory_limit = 2G
max_execution_time = 600

Comment: Are those numbers being respected though? If you create a phpinfo file in your directory and navigate to it, does it match the resources? With shared servers the local php.ini file doesn't always get places above the systems. 

I've also  updated my answer since you provided some error messages.

Comment: Yes, both values match when i execute phpinfo() in a test php file. The shared server provides the possibility to change some values.